# why would django not find templates for installed 3rd party apps that are in site-packages?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-settings, django-middleware

I recently spun off an old project and tried installing its apps (which worked) and also installing django-helpdesk/bootstrap_forms. But django could find neither helpdesk templates, or bootstrapform templates. My settings.py looks like:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'key'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'index',
    'taggit',
    'helpdesk',
    'bootstrapform',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

HELPDESK_PATH       = "/home/cchilders/.local/virtualenv/new_bookmarks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/helpdesk/templates",
BOOSTRAPFORM_PATH   = "/home/cchilders/.local/virtualenv/new_bookmarks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrapform/templates"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), 
                "/home/cchilders/.local/virtualenv/new_bookmarks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/helpdesk/templates",
                "/home/cchilders/.local/virtualenv/new_bookmarks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrapform/templates",],

        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/cchilders/django_practice/new_bookmarks/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I don't have an issue now, but am very confused as to why I had to manually do HELPDESK_PATH and BOOSTRAPFORM_PATH. The last time I spun this up, installing the apps worked out the box, with the same TEMPLATE configs. I have these installed:

```
Django==1.8.3
argparse==1.2.1
betterpath==0.2.2
django-bootstrap-form==3.2
django-extensions==1.5.5
django-helpdesk==0.1.16
django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
django-mptt==0.7.4
django-taggit==0.16.2
email-reply-parser==0.3.0
ipython==3.2.1
l==0.3.1
lxml==3.4.4
markdown2==2.3.0
pytz==2015.4
requests==2.7.0
simplejson==3.8.0
six==1.9.0
vcversioner==2.14.0.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.1.2
```

I am running a VE (like I was when it found templates) and packages are where expected:

`~/.local/virtualenv/new_bookmarks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrapform/templates`

When turning off the new URLS back to `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), ],` I get

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /helpdesk/
helpdesk/public_homepage.html


Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/cchilders/django_practice/new_bookmarks/templates/helpdesk/public_homepage.html (File does not exist)
```

and I don't get why it isn't checking the usual places. My VE works, if I deactive it I can't runserver due to missing packages like 'taggit'. What usually causes django to ignore site-packages and not look for templates beyond BASE_DIR/templates? Thank you

Comment: Isn't it because you have set APP_DIRS to False?

Comment: Yes that was why. I thought they conflict for some reason, and had been doing it like that for a while. Thank you mr. Roseman